# How to parse through the SQL output stored in a Shell variable in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql

This is the shell script I have written to get data from report_data table from "merlin" database.

```
data=$(mysql merlin -BNe 'select * from report_data')
echo "$data"
```

The Output produced is

```
1   1634036113  701 NULL    NULL    monitor-localhost-616569842d586 Service latency 0   1   1   0   OK: service latency min/avg/max = 0.00/0.00/0.20    NULL
2   1634036123  701 NULL    NULL    monitor-localhost-616569842d586 Zombie process  0   1   1   0   OK: 0 zombie process(es)    NULL
3   1634036131  701 NULL    NULL    monitor-localhost-616569842d586 Host orphans    0   1   1   0   OK: Orphaned host checks:   NULL
```

These are the columns present in the table -

```
| id  | timestamp  | event_type | flags | attrib | host_name                       | service_description                 | state | hard | retry | downtime_depth | output                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | long_output |
```

I want to use every row as individual entity and want to parse through it.

Comment: Why can't you get the output in CSV, JSON or other more processing-friendly formats?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you ming explaining what you mean with "parse through" the individual rows?

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?

Comment: I have to send the data to a webhook endpoint, so will be requiring to store this like an array. Eg: If I say data[0][1], the output should be 1634036113..something that we do in normal programming languages. Just like looping through each row.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mysql merlin -e "SELECT * FROM report_data" | while read id timestamp event_type flags attrib host_name; do
    
#echo "$id | $timestamp | $event_type | $flags | $attrib | $host_name"

array+=("$id | $timestamp | $event_type | $flags | $attrib | $host_name")

done
```

<s>I just print it out but you can do whatever you want such as adding them into an array row by row.</s>

Comment: Hi, I would like to store the output of the query in variable preferably like array, and loop through it for accessing individual values.

Comment: @Cipher, As I mentioned in my post, instead of printing the row you can simply assign it to an array. eg: `array+=("$id | $timestamp | $event_type | $flags | $attrib | $host_name")`

Comment: @Cipher There is absolutely no gain in storing the output of `mysql` in an intermediate variable.

Comment: @TariqHawis If you really want to read stuff into an array, use `readarray`.